# Layering iOS Animations

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I'm having some trouble layering iOS animations for my video recoding button. I've modeled it after other standard recording buttons and **I'd like for it to begin as a solid circle and then on press, transform to a rounded rectangle where its opacity pulses**.

The issue is that I've ordered the animations in a way such that their all applied at the same time.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8lzx.jpg

I've tried reordering these animations but can't figure out which ordering with achieve the scope I want.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var recordComplete = false
    @State private var rCorner: CGFloat = 100
    @State private var rWidth: CGFloat = 70
    @State private var rHeight: CGFloat = 70
    @State private var opacityVal = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Button(action: {
                self.rCorner = self.rCorner == 100 ? 12 : 100
                self.rWidth = self.rWidth == 70 ? 45 : 70
                self.rHeight = self.rHeight == 70 ? 45 : 70
                self.recordComplete.toggle()
                
            }) {
                ZStack{
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 6)
                        .frame(width:85, height: 85)
                
                    
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: rCorner)
                        .fill(Color.red)
                        .frame(width: rWidth, height: rHeight)
                        .opacity(opacityVal)
                        .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true)).onAppear{ self.opacityVal = 0.3 }
                    
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 25)
                
            }
        }.animation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 2, blendDuration: 0.5))
    }
}
```

Thank you as always for the help with this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution - the main idea is to separate animations by value and make them serial. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var recordComplete = false
    @State private var rCorner: CGFloat = 100
    @State private var rWidth: CGFloat = 70
    @State private var rHeight: CGFloat = 70
    @State private var opacityVal = 1.0

    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Button(action: {
                self.rCorner = self.rCorner == 100 ? 12 : 100
                self.rWidth = self.rWidth == 70 ? 45 : 70
                self.rHeight = self.rHeight == 70 ? 45 : 70

                self.recordComplete.toggle()
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                    self.opacityVal = self.recordComplete ? 0.3 : 1.0
                }
            }) {
                ZStack{
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 6)
                        .frame(width:85, height: 85)


                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: rCorner)
                        .fill(Color.red)
                        .frame(width: rWidth, height: rHeight)
                        .opacity(opacityVal)
                        .animation(
                            self.recordComplete ?
                                Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true) :
                                Animation.default,
                            value: opacityVal)
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 25)

            }
        }.animation(.spring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 2, blendDuration: 0.5), value: rCorner)
    }
}
```